# What is an appropriate loop for a function with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, iteration

The function nb_year should return n number of entire years needed to get a population greater or equal to p.The given parameters are p0(original population), percent(percentage of increase), aug (inhabitants coming or leaving each year), p (population to surpass) i understand what the math is to get the result i just don't know what type of loop i should write to keep increasing the numbers. here is my current code

```
function nbYear(p0, percent, aug, p) {
   var increaseInHab = p0 * (percent * .01);
   var currentInhab = increaseInHab + p0 + aug;

   for(var n = 0;currentInHab < p;n++) {
     console.log(n)
     n++
     console.log(currentInhab + increaseInHab);
     currentInhab + increaseInHab;
    }
   return n;
}
```

Comment: `currentInhab + increaseInHab;` adds two numbers and does nothing with the result. Hint, you need to store it back into the variable you want to update.

Comment: It should be avoided in general, use a JSON-param instead.

Comment: @Blauharley Are we reading the same question???? What is a "JSON-param"

Comment: Recursion is the process generally used when modeling populations.

Comment: _"aug (inhabitants coming or leaving each year)"_ `aug` is expected to be position number, negative number or `0`? _"i just don't know what type of loop i should write to keep increasing the numbers."_ If `aug` can be a negative number,  the numbers are not guaranteed to increase, yes?

Comment: Perfect circumstances for a while loop. The number or type of parameters doesn't matter one bit, what you want to do is do something while a certain condition isn't met, the definition of a while loop.

Comment: `currentInhab = currentInhab + increaseInHab;`

Comment: Also: `currentInhab += increaseInHab;`

Comment: @epascarello: This comment does not fit, but this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/7ee6fg/better-way-of-passing-multiple-parameters-to-a-function-in-javascript) may does. It explain of what a meant hopefully.

Comment: Population analysis and statistical representation of a forecast graph  include many variables not present at `javascript` at Question. If requirement is to only increase the return value of the function at Question, pass only positive numbers to the function; for example, at `aug` parameter.

Comment: ok so i used a while loop instead and got my code to loop properly but know how to i return my new p0 with the increase to the function    function

Answer (score 2):

Good loop, but implementation needs fixing.

```
function nbYear(p0, percent, aug, p) {
   var increaseInHab = p0 * (percent * .01);
   var currentInhab = increaseInHab + p0 + aug;

   for(var n = 0; currentInHab < p; n++) {
     currentInhab += increaseInHab;
   }

   return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the specific details of your code (I'm assuming the multiplication expressions are correct), below would be a quick fix for your `for` loop problems:

```
function nbYear(p0, percent, aug, p) {
    var increaseInHab = p0 * (percent * .01);
    var currentInhab = increaseInHab + p0 + aug;
    var n = 0;

    for (; currentInHab < p; n++) {
       currentInhab + increaseInHab;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Also, you were incrementing `n` twice.

Comment: I'm confused. I did not use `let`

Comment: You assumed that `var` works the way `let` does, but it doesn't. Your code was identical to the OP's before the edit and now it just has one less `n++` and the logging is removed, but moving the declaration of `n` has no effect..

Comment: I don't see `let` being used in my original answer, edited answer, nor the author's original question.

Comment: Exactly, `var` is used in both the OP's post and your answer, not `let`, so it ***doesn't matter where in the function `n` is declared***. It would only matter if `let` was used, but it isn't.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to communicate now. I did not before.